# AggregateGraphLookupOptions mongo GraphLookup set

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregate

how to set options to **GraphLookup**,
Now setting options I can't set Generic types.

```
  var options = new **AggregateGraphLookupOptions<BsonDocument, BsonDocument, BsonDocument>**
            {
                MaxDepth = 2,
            };

var ss1 = aggregate.GraphLookup(this.EntitiesCol, "To", "From", startField, "destinations", **options**);
```

after ss1 I am using for match and grouping...

Error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0411  The type arguments for method
>   'IAggregateFluent.GraphLookup(IMongoCollection, FieldDefinition, FieldDefinition,
>   AggregateExpressionDefinition,
>   FieldDefinition, FieldDefinition,
>   AggregateGraphLookupOptions)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.   Abc.eStepControl.Infrastructure F:\ABC\eStepControl\eStepControl\EngineGit\dev\eStepControl.Engine\src\eStepControl.Infrastructure\Repositories\EdgesRepository.cs  684 Active

Answer (score 0):

Use AppendStage() method to add graphLookup stage as follows:

```
var graphLookupStage = new BsonDocument("$graphLookup",
                        new BsonDocument
                            {
                                    { "from", "someCollection" },
                                    { "startWith", "$reportsTo" },
                                    { "connectFromField", "reportsTo"},
                                    { "connectToField",  "name" },
                                    { "as", "reportingHierarchy" },
                                    { "maxDepth", 1 },
                                    { "depthField", "depthField" } //optional
                        });
var result = collection.Aggregate().AppendStage<BsonDocument>(graphLookupStage);
```